# How do I write a bash script that makes a phone call on my cell once a matlab process finishes?

Tags: bash, voip, matlab

If not a call, is sending a text message possible?

I have tried setting up an email notification and that worked, but I would prefer if I got a call or a message.

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. There is a lot of information missing here to be able to give you an answer at all. What type of phone and make. Have you considered SMS-gateways? If you rewrite your question to include these things and what you have done so far to resolve your problem, then I think the chances of getting a proper answer is much higher.

Comment: You can look here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16649-send-text-message-to-cell-phone or here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17416-txtmsg-create to find functions that will let you send a text message from MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

If you can send yourself an email, you can probably send yourself a text message by using an email-to-SMS gateway:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways